# Powershell silent mkdir

Tags: powershell, mkdir

Is there a way to use mkdir (aka md) in powershell without verbose output? Currently, the output is as follows:

```
PS C:\Users\myusername> mkdir foobar


    Directory: C:\Users\myusername


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----        2016-12-07   9:35 AM            foobar
PS C:\Users\myusername>
```

Unless there's an error to report, I'd like it to be silent, as in

```
PS C:\Users\myusername> mkdir foobar
PS C:\Users\myusername>
```

Is there a way to do this? I'm using Powershell version 2.

Comment: How about `| Out-Null`?

Comment: In which context would you want it to be silent? Just in a specific location in a script or always?

Comment: PetSerAl - That works. It preserves errors, too (at least, it doesn't redirect stderr to null)

Comment: Seth - Just in interactive use. It's not a serious problem, but I've found that the verbose output makes reading previous commands more difficult, especially in that it forces me to scroll my command prompt window up more than I would otherwise need to.

Comment: `mkdir | out-null`, `mkdir > $null`, `$null = mkdir`, `[void]mkdir` are your options, I always use `> $null` because it's faster than `| out-null` - see this for reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260125/whats-the-better-cleaner-way-to-ignore-output-in-powershell

Answer (score 17, accepted):

PetSerAl is correct, added to by SimonS

`Out-Null` is your best bet but as SimonS stated `> $null` is quicker

Comment: Thanks! I would have marked PetSerAl's answer as correct, but since I can't this one gets the kudos.

Comment: nope, doesn't work in PS for win 10.

Comment: Instead, this seems to fail silently: [system.io.directory]::CreateDirectory("C:\test")

Comment: @FizxMike sorry just seen this, works for me on a pretty regular basis on windows 10.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add another solution: `mkdir` returns an object and if I just execute the code below, I don't have any output. Further more, I can use `$dir` to make my own output if needed

```
$dir = mkdir c:\foo\bar
```

As a side note, I've tested this PowerShell Version

```
PS> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      15063  1155
```

Comment: This one seems to me as cool, clean and practical solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make a function

```
function silentMkdir { $sink = mkdir $args }
```

Make an alias in the current shell only that uses that function

```
Set-Alias -Name mkdir -Value silentMkdir -Scope Private
```

PS: I'm new to Powershell but this seemed to work. Without the `-Scope Private` mkdir will be changed for scripts called from this shell. With `-Scope Private` that issue seems to go away.